# Create text containing a new line with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I have two texts I want to add together so they are on two consecutive lines. I have found the option to change line spacing so I assume there is a way to add linebreaks.
How can I add a linebreak to a text object with the animation nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Characters Node in Animation Nodes**

[image]

Line Break character is added to a list and then joined for output.

Click image above for larger view.

[image]

[image]

Animation Nodes. Search or Menu.  Composed image above.

Menu >> Add >> Text >> Characters. AN Menus have many items which creates vertical size. Thus the large image to minimize vertical scroll at BSE.

Comment: you can actually plug the "line break" directly into the join node "separator" input, so it happens between many lines if the case

Comment: also worth mentioning that the sockets in "characters" can be hidden so the node becomes smaller